# typedef equivalent for Typescript

Tags: typescript, typedef

I have various types of integer IDs in my app (e.g. ProductId, UserId etc.) which I want to implement strong typing so that I can be sure I am passing the correct ID type to methods.

e.g. I want to declare `GetProduct(productId: ProductId)` instead of `GetProduct(productId: number)` such that only ProductId typed variables can be passed to it.

In my C days, I would use a typedef - e.g. `typedef ProductId int;`

In C#, I accomplished this by defining a ProductId class with an implicit cast to int operator and an explicit cast from int operator. More cumbersome than a typedef, but it works.

I'm trying to figure out how to do the equivalent in TypeScript.
For TypeScript, I tried this:

```
export class ProductId extends Number {}
```

but this still allows a number to be passed in place of a ProductId.

How would one accomplish this in TypeScript?

Comment: Typescript is structurally, not nominally, typed so that isn't supported.

Comment: Can't you use composition in ProductId and have the class expose a setter that validates the value being set? Internally then you could use a number, but since it'd be private, one would have to use the setter.

Comment: @Igor: In such case one will see errors only when the application is running. But the question is rather how to define type, so that during compilation one can see that incompatible parameters are passed to a method. This would have the advantage, that one would save a lot of time an efforts.

Comment: @mentallurg exactly.

Comment: Your question asks how to create a `typedef` equivalent, but then you say you want the types to be unique, so you can't pass an `int` to a parameter of type `ProductId`.  However in C/C++ typedefs don't work like this, you can absolutely pass `int` instead of `ProductId` if it's a `typedef int`.  This is because `typedef` creates an alias (like a macro) not a new type.  So it seems you are actually asking how to define new types that behave similarly to numbers, but you *don't* want an equivalent to C's `typedef`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It is possible to do this, with some effort.

The trick is to define your `ProductID` as something that is in TS different from number, but still a number when actually running as Javascript.

I wrote about this on my blog here: https://evertpot.com/opaque-ts-types/

But I will share the important details here:

```
declare const validProductId: unique symbol;

type ProductId = number & {
  [validProductId]: true
}
```

Note that even though we declared a 'unique symbol', this is completely stripped from Javascript, so there's not *actually* a symbol added to your `ProductId`, which would be a pain.

To actually get a something recognized as a `ProductId`, you will need to write either an assertion function, a type guard function or just cast from a place where `ProductId`'s are actually allowed to be generated.

And just to repeat, there is no actual need to have add this symbol to your `ProductId`, this is *just* to make sure that Typescript recognizes `ProductId` as a distinct type from `number`. During runtime, it's just a `number`.

This is a *great* pattern for your use-case. It's basically a marker that this is not just any number, it's specifically a number that has been vetted by your business logic as a product id.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that in TypeScript.

Using aliases does not prevent from passing values of other type. If you declare type *B* as alias of type *A*, in all places where type *B* is expected you can pass also parameters of type *A* and vice versa.

What about encapsulating one type into another? Suppose types *A* and *B* both have a single member of type *number*. Will such wrapper help? 
No. The compatibility of classes and interfaces in TypeScript is determined based on their structure. If two different types have *identical* structure they are compatible. It is possible to use one instead of another.